# show feature on google map(desktop app contains a web browser) using Google Map APIs

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a tree view and a web browser in my desktop application in which tree view contains a list of coordinates values or say centroid of features now what i want only to show particular point on my web browser google map api when user click on any tree view node.

precondition:-
1. when user click on tree view node we got map coordinate to show on google map which i already set in my web browser using google map APIs.

Answer (score -1):

```
**you need to replace your key with googleapikey and set your key and you need to use below script with set your values to  and from address** 

  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=yourgoogleapikey" type="text/javascript">


    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var toAddress = "650 Franklin Street, Suite 306, Schenectady, NY, 12305, USA";
        var directions; //Google directions object
        window.onload = getDir;
        var fromStreet = '';
        var fromZip = "12345";
        var dirpanel;
        var divMap;

        function getDir() {
            if (!directions) {
                divMap = document.getElementById("divMap");
                dirMap = new GMap2(divMap);
                dirMap.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
                dirMap.addControl(new GScaleControl());

                dirpanel = document.getElementById("divRoute");
                directions = new GDirections(dirMap, dirpanel);
                GEvent.addListener(directions, "error", handleErrors);
            }

            //Clear Directions, if any
            dirpanel.innerHTML = "";

            var fromAddress = '';
            //At least starting zip/city & state is needed to get the directions

            if (fromZip.length > 0) {
                if (fromStreet.length > 0)
                    fromAddress = fromStreet + ", ";
                fromAddress += fromZip;
                directions.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress);
                divMap.style.visibility = "";
            }

        }

        function handleErrors() {
            divMap.style.visibility = "hidden";
            if (directions.getStatus().code == G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS) {
                alert("We are unable to show directions for the starting address you entered.\nThis may be because the from address is relatively new, or it may be incorrect.");
            }
            else {
                alert("We apologize!\n\nWe are currently unable to display directions for this location");
            }
        }

        //]]>
    </script>
```